# Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 6:6. Type ResourcesDictionary not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, visual-studio-2015, cross-platform

Please help, when implementing the app, I get the following error message:: Xamarin.Forms.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 6:6. Type ResourcesDictionary not found in xmlns http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is ResourceDictionary instead of ResourcesDictionary, you are spelling it wrong...

Comment: Indeed that was the mistake, I had not seen, thank you very much for your help.